# Heroku Review App not caching node_modules

Tags: node.js, heroku, npm, yarnpkg, buildpack

I use the following buildpack: [heroku-buildpack-nodejs](https://github.com/heroku/heroku-buildpack-nodejs)
And by default, it should cache and restore `node_modules`.

`yarn.lock` file is located at the root of the application along with `package.json`.

I've also added `"cacheDirectories": [".cache/yarn"]` to `package.json`

During the review-app build log analysis, I see:

```
-----> Restoring cache
Loading 1 from cacheDirectories (package.json):
- .cache/yarn (not cached - skipping)
```

...

```
-----> Installing dependencies
       Installing node modules (yarn.lock)
```

...

```
-----> Caching build
       - node_modules
```

Seems like this issue was opened on Dec 20, 2016 :
https://github.com/heroku/heroku-buildpack-nodejs/issues/359

How can I achieve the caching mechanism without installing the dependencies on every build?

Answer (score 0):

> [v83](https://github.com/heroku/heroku-buildpack-nodejs/blob/v83/bin/compile) of Heroku NodeJS build pack has no support for installing dependencies with yarn. This was added in [v93](https://github.com/heroku/heroku-buildpack-nodejs/blob/v93/bin/compile).

Buildpack v93 is not without its own issues. Since it hard codes the [yarn cache path](https://github.com/heroku/heroku-buildpack-nodejs/blob/v93/lib/dependencies.sh#L32) relative to `$build_dir` as `$build_dir/.cache/yarn/v2`.
This presents an issue as `$build_dir` is a temporary directory and can't be relied to exist in the next deployment.

To demonstrate this, add a `heroku-postbuild` or `heroku-prebuild` command script for `scripts` key in `package.json` to show the folder deployment is running in.

```
"heroku-postbuild": "pwd"
```

Part output of build logs

```sh
remote:        $ echo 'postbuild'; pwd
remote:        postbuild
remote:        /tmp/build_260cb9d4ad95c7671332f8a404117b59
remote:        Done in 0.10s.
```

Some issues with yarn deployments are addressed in later version of the buildpack. I recommend using the latest build pack which currently is [v165](https://github.com/heroku/heroku-buildpack-nodejs/blob/v165/bin/compile)

In v165, [the cache is copied from the temporary folder](https://github.com/heroku/heroku-buildpack-nodejs/blob/v165/lib/cache.sh#L55) where yarn caches dependencies to that configured for `cacheDirectories` key in `package.json`

Currently, this feature is behind a feature flag.

In order to enable it for your deployment, create a `features` file in your project.

```sh
.
├── README.md
├── features
├── package.json
└── yarn.lock
```

In `features` file, write

```
cache-native-yarn-cache=true
```

Re-running your deployment should produce a log similar with:

```
remote:
remote: -----> Restoring cache
remote:        Loading 1 from cacheDirectories (package.json):
remote:        - .cache/yarn
```

Comment: Oluwafemi it is not working, and I'm still getting: - .yarn_cache (not cached - skipping)